# what is the correct way of using not:() function for RTL and LTR rules in CSS

Tags: html, css

I applied a global div { direction: rtl ; } to my teachable school because the school is in Arabic language. but I also want to exclude certain elements from that rule (english texts, video players, sign up forms .etc) 
so I tried using the not:() function to exclude those elements and here's the code:

div:not(.spc):not(.lecture-attachment-type-video):not(.quiz-content):not(.lecture-sidebar) {
    direction: rtl;
}

the global div {direction: rtl; } is working correctly but the :not() isn't. these classes are still in rtl.

any ideas?
thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you not "overwrite" the property with additional selectors like `#block-... { direction: ltr; }`? So you define the default direction and switch it for specific elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s an inherited property, so not applying a rule with `direction` to those elements will just let them inherit that same `direction` from their parents. So to do it with CSS,

```css
/* set it for the document: */
body {
    direction: rtl;
}

/* then reset it for the appropriate elements: */
.spc, .lecture-attachment-type-video, .quiz-content, .lecture-sidebar {
    direction: ltr;
}
```

… but if the text direction is a property of the content, which it usually is, HTML tends to be the better place to note that:

```
<body dir="rtl">
    ⋮
    <div class="spc" dir="ltr">…</div>
    ⋮
</body>
```

Comment: so using { direction: rtl; } alot won't cause too much trouble?

Comment: @AhmedDhahir: A lot how? Isn’t it just once?

Comment: sorry for the unclear question. 
my site has both RTL and LTR texts and they are interconnected (German language course for Arabic speakers )
I've set the direction to be RTL because there's more RTL text than LTR but where I have LTR elements I have to overwrite the global css rule (RTL).
therefore I have to use that "alot".
My question is, can this approach be harmful? 
my first post here, still a n00b. thanks in advance

Comment: @AhmedDhahir: No, you don’t have to worry – the way browsers apply CSS makes it not very different.